# how to change one thread to another thread in RoundRobin Scheduling using Java

Tags: java, scheduling, round-robin

The files are given, I am supposed to edit only BLOCK#2 part in the RoundRobinScheduler class. 
I tried to use the index to schedule each thread. It ran successfully in order but could not switch from one thread to another thread as "RoundRobin" scheduling.
Does Thread has any function that could let the thread into ready state, and run the next thread?

Following are classes:

```
package operating_system;

class TestScheduler extends Thread {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scheduler mySched =  new RoundRobinScheduler();
                //new RandomScheduler() ;
        // or new RoundRobinScheduler() - when written
        // or new PriorityScheduler()  - when written
    Thread p1 = new SimProc(mySched, "Alan", 4) ;
    Thread p2 = new SimProc(mySched, "Brian", 4) ;
    Thread p3 = new SimProc(mySched, "Charles", 4) ; 
    Thread p4 = new SimProc(mySched, "Dave", 4) ;
    Thread p5 = new SimProc(mySched, "Edward", 4) ;
    Thread p6 = new SimProc(mySched, "Francis", 4) ;
    mySched.start() ;
    }

}
```

```
package operating_system;

import java.util.Random ;

class SimProc extends Thread {

    private Scheduler mySched ; 
    private int count ;
    private static Random threadSeed = new Random() ;

    private static long getSeed() {
        return 1 + threadSeed.nextLong() ; 
    }

    public SimProc(Scheduler sch, String name, int i) {
        super(name) ;
        mySched = sch ;
        count = i ;
        synchronized (this) { 
            start() ;
            try {
                wait() ; // for process to be ready
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
       return count ;
    }

    private int collatz(int i) {
        int ans = 0 ;
        while (i != 1) {
            if (i <= 0) return -1 ; // numbers get too big!
            ans++ ;
            if (i % 2 == 0) i /= 2 ;
            else i = i*3 + 1 ;
        }
        return ans ;
    }

    private void addToReadyQueue() {
        mySched.addProcess(this) ;
        synchronized (this) {
            notify() ; // so constructor completes
            try { 
                wait() ; // so process is waiting when scheduler starts
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    private void removeFromReadyQueue() {
        mySched.removeProcess(this) ;
        mySched.endSlice(this) ; // want something else to run!
    }

    public void run() {
        addToReadyQueue() ;
        Random myrand = new Random(getSeed()) ;
        while(count > 0) {
            int k = Math.abs(myrand.nextInt()) ;
            int ans = collatz(k) ;
            if (ans > 0) count-- ;
            System.out.println("This is " + getName() + " - Collatz of "
            + k + " is " + ans) ;
            mySched.endSlice(this) ;

        }
        removeFromReadyQueue() ;
    }
}
```

```
package operating_system;

import java.util.ArrayList ;

abstract public class Scheduler extends Thread {

protected ArrayList <SimProc> processList ;
    public Scheduler() {
      processList = new ArrayList <SimProc> () ;
    }

   public synchronized void addProcess(SimProc t) {
      processList.add(t) ;
   }

   public void endSlice(SimProc t) {
        synchronized(t) {
            synchronized(this) { notify() ; }
        try { t.wait() ;}
        catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Unexpected interrupt in endSlice " + e) ;
        }
    }
   }    

   public synchronized void removeProcess(SimProc t) {
    int i = processList.indexOf(t) ;
    processList.remove(i) ;
   }
}
```

```
package operating_system;

import java.util.Random ;

public class RoundRobinScheduler extends Scheduler {

private Random randGen ;

    public RoundRobinScheduler() {
         randGen = new Random() ;
    }

    public void removeProcess( int index ){
         processList.remove(index);
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
    while (true) {
     //BLOCK 1
        int noProcs = processList.size() ;
        if (noProcs == 0) System.exit(0) ;
     //BLOCK 2
        int curProcs = 0;
        int next;
        if ( curProcs == noProcs )
                next = 0;
        else next = curProcs++;
        SimProc nextRunner = processList.get( next );
        synchronized( nextRunner ){ nextRunner.notify();}
     //BLOCK 3
        try { wait() ;}
        catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Unexpected interrupt in run " + e) ; 
        }
        //removeProcess( curProcs );
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thread switching is already implemented using the `Scheduler.nextSlice()` and `synchronized( nextRunner ){ nextRunner.notify();}` parts.
What is missing is that you are actually starting the SimProc objects at the first time:

```
SimProc nextRunner = processList.get( next );
if(nextRunner.isAlive()) {
  synchronized( nextRunner ){ nextRunner.notify();}
} else {
  nextRunner.start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, from the result, it scheduled in order but still could not switch from thread1 to thread2 and ... everytime the thread finishes one output. It supposed to be like 'This is Alan... This is Brian...This is Alan...This is Brian...' rather than 'This is Alan... This is Alan ...This is Alan...This is Brian... This is Brain...'.